# What are these javaScript vim messages?

Tags: vim

When I open a file in vim with `vim filename -c syn off` I get messages mentioned below  inside `vim`

```
javaScriptComment xxx start=+/\*+ end=+\*/+  contains=@Spell,javaScriptCommentTodo
                   links to Comment
javaScriptSpecial xxx match /\\\d\d\d\|\\./
                       links to Special
-- More --
```

What are these? I don't work in Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vim filename -c syn off` is like:

```
vim -c syn filename off
```

You're opening two files named `filename` and `off`, and running the `:syn` command after opening Vim. The `:syn` command without arguments just dumps the current syntax highlighting configuration for the current buffer. For `filename`, whatever the actual filename is, that apparently includes some JavaScript syntax highlighting as well.

You want:

```
vim filename -c "syn off"
```

Comment: Better form to put `-c` _after_ the filename? That's surprising, given the POSIX preference for options to precede positional arguments (see [utility syntax guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), particularly guideline 9)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was showing the minimal change needed to fix OP's original command. (But `-c` with Vim is a case where it does make sense to do so - the command specified by `-c` is run *after* the file is loaded, so it might be easier for some to visualise the sequence of actions.)